# Rails Active record null after passed to class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, helper

I want to be able to pass my user object to another class for validation. Basically I do something like

My Controller:

```
def new

  user = User.find(1)
  logger.info "#{user.id}, #{user.name}, #{user.isadmin}"
  #The above is logged with 1, test, true
  uhelper = UserHelper.new(user)
  if !uhelper.isAdmin
    #Only admins can access this page
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

## in app/models

```
Class UserHelper

def initialize(user)
  @user = user
end

def isAdmin
  if @user.isadmin
    true
  end
    nil
end
```

The if statement in the controller is always resolving to nil even though I know the record is correct. Can I not pass ActiveRecords to classes like that correctly?

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

## Edit

```
undefined method `isadmin' for nil:NilClass
app/models/userfnc.rb:14:in `isAdmin'
app/controllers/rosters_controller.rb:12:in `index'

sqlite> select * from users;
1|testuser|test@test.com|20170601|20170601|1

sqlite> .schema users
CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar DEFAULT NULL, "email" varchar DEFAULT NULL, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, "isadmin" boolean);
```

Comment: `isAdmin` will always return `nil` because you told it to. If `nil` is supposed to be the else response then restructure your `isAdmin` method to use `if ... else ... end`. Also for `ActiveRecord` booleans the standard convention is to call the "boolean method" so rather than `@user.isadmin` it would be `@user.isadmin?` (with a question mark at the end). finally what is `userfnc`? should probably be either "app/models/user.rb" or "app/helpers/user_helper.rb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a bit of code improvements you could use to your code.

As to your problem, it's possible that your casing is getting you.  Check your table.  your field might be called `isadmin` not `isAdmin`.

As for your code improvements, here's what could help you:

```
def isAdmin
  if @user.isAdmin
    true
  end
    nil
end
```

you could accomplish this with one line:

```
def isAdmin
  @user.isAdmin
end
```

This bit,

```
uhelper = UserHelper.new(user)
if !uhelper.isAdmin
  #Only admins can access this page
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

When you have a simple expression like this, sometimes it's easier to also reduce this to one line:

```
uhelper = UserHelper.new(user)
redirect_to root_path unless uhelper.isAdmin
```

**However...**  Rails standards are to use filters in this case.  Instead of that bit at all, put this in a filter method.

```
class MyController
  before_filter :check_admin
  ...
  ...
  private
  def check_admin
    redirect_to root_path unless user.isAdmin
  end
end
```